# Create composite key from foreign key and DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, orm

I just started using EF. A User has 0 or more Weights, but only at most one for the same Date. How do I accomplish this? I think I should create a composite key, but I don´t find any proper attribute to add before the Date property.
This is my two models:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Weight> Weights { get; set; }
}

public class Weight
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Generally, you are better off using a unique id key (not necessarily a GUID) and then use an index to facilitate access by multiple values and enforce unique constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you are trying to store the weight fluctuation against a period and it wouldn't make sense to have two different weights at the same exact date and time. With that in mind you could just add the attribute [key] to UserID and Date properties in the Weight class.

With this design, when you query the weights from the database, you could order them by the date and time values of the Date property and the last item will be the most recent weight measure.